# How to read the reset vector on an ATMEGA328

Tags: arduino, atmega

I have several ATMEGA328 based custom boards: I recently found that the standard Arduino bootloader does not handle watchdog timeouts correctly (it keeps resetting, so the device is effectively bricked until the next power cycle) so I am switching to the Optiboot bootloader.

I want to add something to my app that tells me whether the bootloader is Arduino or Optiboot. As Optiboot is a lot smaller, the reset vector is different, so printing that out would be a good indication.

> Serial.println (pgm_read_word_near(0), HEX);

The above line of code prints out 940C, and I was expecting something like 7E00. How can I print out the address from the reset vector?

Comment: Optiboot is the standard Arduino bootloader for 328p

Comment: @Juraj unfortunately the Arduino IDE doesn't seem to know that. Many devices use it, but 8MHz Pro Mini still uses the standard bootloader. That's why my board locks up of there is a watchdog timeout.

Comment: did you notice the answer?

Comment: I did notice your answer, but it does not answer the question "How can I print out the address from the reset vector"? It assumes that the lock bits have been set correctly for the bootloader size, which may not necessarily be true.

Comment: from datasheet: The reset vector can also be moved to the start of the boot flash section by programming the BOOTRST fuse. The actual address of the start of the boot flash section is determined by the BOOTSZ fuses.

Answer (score 0):

The actual address of the start of the boot flash section is determined by the BOOTSZ fuses.

This reads the size of the bootloader for classic ATmega:

```
  uint32_t bootloaderSize;
  cli();
  uint8_t highBits = boot_lock_fuse_bits_get(GET_HIGH_FUSE_BITS);
  sei();
  if (!(highBits & bit(FUSE_BOOTRST))) {
    uint8_t v = (highBits & ((~FUSE_BOOTSZ1 ) + (~FUSE_BOOTSZ0 )));
    bootloaderSize = MIN_BOOTSZ << ((v >> 1) ^ 3);
  }
```

use `#include <avr/boot.h>`